# Changing TextString field in ArcMap annotations not resulting in changed annotations on map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, annotation

I am having an issue with ArcMap while trying to save myself a lot of work.

I recently had to individually place hundreds of annotations for a large map. Without getting into too much detail the labels I placed were at the section level which means something like 1st Street would be annotated as 1ST-01,1ST-02,1ST-03, etc for different sections of the street. However, the client also wants a map at the branch level instead of the section level which means the annotations would just say 1ST without any section. The "-" is pretty useful for this and I opened up the annotation attribute table in excel,  used a formula to remove everything after "-" and bam I got branch labels without having to place them again from scratch.

I then joined this excel sheet to a copy of the section annotation layer and used the field calculator to make the TextString field equal to the trimmed down Section IDs. This worked and all the TextString fields are updated, but on the map they have not changed.

Is it because I did this in excel and tried to join it back?

Is there an easier way to remove everything after a "-" in the field calculator?

Comment: Did you remove the join and did you save the edits? The text field with the changes needs to be called exactly TextString and a join might mess that up by qualifying the field name. I would also poke around in Edit in a few records and retype text to see if the changes show up on the map.

Comment: "Is there an easier way to remove everything after a "-" in the field calculator?" - yes.  Exporting to Excel, re-joining and calculating is the long way around.  In field calculator a Python expression something like the following should result in everything up to, but not including, the first "-":  `!TextField!.split('-')[0]` .  (Test on a copy before trying on real data!  You cannot undo this.)